# Recover adobe muse file project

Tags: ftp, adobe, backup, muse

I deleted the file project of my website, but I have only my ftp file, so now my site works, but I can't edit it anymore. Can I create a new file project from my file on the ftp?

Ps
My abobe CC account had not created a backup

Answer (score 0):

nope

free tools for recovering your files http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/best-free-recovery-software-1141256